# How to change limitToFirst() dynamically in recyclerview firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here i set firebase adapter in recyclerview.
In which i used  Query like this.

```
Query sortPost=PostRef.orderByChild("count").limitToFirst(firstTenPost);
```

In tihs firstTenPost is int variable. Now i want to change its value dynamically by some detection.

Lets take an example,
Suppose i have button outside of recyclerview and if i set onClickListner on button, so it should be like this,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //here, can i change the value of firstTenPost variable//
                  firstTenPost=firstTenPost+10;


            }
        });
```

So its possible or not ? if yes than please explain

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, a pagination system?

Comment: yes,   @AlexMamo you are right

Comment: It's a very common topic. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firebase+pagination.

Comment: you say "a pagination system?" its should be like this 
but i dont know about this topic and logics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support offset queries. So while you can say "give me the first 10 nodes matching these conditions", you can't then later say "give me the next 10 nodes".

The two broad options you have to implement pagination are:

1. Use an ever-growing page-size. So when you show the first page you `limitToFirst(10)`, then for page 2 you use `limitToFirst(20)`, and so on.

   ```
   PostRef.orderByChild("count").limitToFirst(20);
   ```

   This is pretty simple, but does lead to you reading more data than is needed for the subsequent pages. Usually this is not a big problem, as long as the user doesn't browse too many pages down.
2. Firebase's query model is based on an anchor document. So while you can't say "skip 10 nodes", you **can** tell a query to start at a specific node.

   So if you know the last node of the first page, you can create aquery that retrieves that last node of page 1 and then the next 10 nodes. In order to do that, you'll need to know the `count` value (the property you ordered on) and the key of the last node on the previous page.

   Say that the last node on page 1 had a count equal to 100, and key `-Ldfo731rl`, you can get the nodes for the next page with:

   ```
   PostRef.orderByChild("count").startAt(100, "-Ldfo731rl").limitToFirst(10);
   ```

As Alex commented, the topic of pagination with the Firebase Realtime Database has been covered quite a lot already here, so I recommend you check out some other [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firebase+pagination).